# call API in react modal gave infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

        if(nextProps.isOpen){
            const { selectedItemId} = this.props;
            //ajax 
        }
    }
```

I have a modal component that needs to call API, I do it like this, isOpen is a flag to open and close the modal, but with this approach I got infinite calls.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` will be called whenever there is a change in the props. It can be from reacts internal state or your own apps state. Write your `ajax` in `componentDidMount` and don't render your `modal` until `isOpen` is true.

Comment: I do a console.log in my modal's contstuctor, it triggered when I load the page that includes it. What do you mean by don't render?

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` will be called `n` number of times. You have to conditionally render your modal in the parent component's render method like `{ this.state.isOpen ? (<YourModal />) : null }`

Answer (score 0):

Just use a flag to not request all the time while you are requesting / rendering

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.isOpen && !this.requesting){
        const { selectedItemId } = this.props;
        this.requesting = true;
        //ajax 
        ajax.then( () => {
            this.requesting = false;
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: this is strange though, I think what Panther said make more sense.

Comment: it depends on how you want the thing to work and also how you need it to. For instance if you need to make requests while the modal is open (say you click on something in the modal and then need to make a request). Your question isn't really clear on the use case so I just wrote it for your current implementation.